# Looping through a nested attribute with external model details

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

three-months-in beginner with Ruby on Rails here, so I apologize if any of my terminology is incorrect.  I have a question about referencing outside models from a nested attribute.

I have three models.  Tasks with nested attributes for Task Products, and a separate Items table with pre-populated products.

Each Task has many Task Products, and the Task Product has a "product_id" column which is in reference to an existing product in the Item table.  In creating an table index of each Task, I am having trouble figuring out how to have the nested Task Product's product_id's list out the Item instead of just the bare id.

Here's the code I'm working with:

tasks_controller.rb -->

```
def dashboard
  @tasks = Task.includes(:task_products, :storeorder).last(100)
  @tasks.each do |task|
    task.storeorder do |storeorder|
    end
    task.task_products.each do |task_product|
      @item = Item.where(:id => task_product.product_id)
    end
  end
end
```

task.rb -->

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :task_products
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :task_products
end
```

task_product.rb -->

```
class TaskProduct < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :task
  has_many :items
end
```

item.rb -->

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task_product

  def item_select
    "#{vendor_name} (#{description})"
  end
end
```

dashboard.html.erb -->

```
<td>
  <% t.task_products.each do |tp| %>
    # Existing code that lists each task product in a list on the table:
    <p><%= tp.product_id %></p>
    # The ideal code I would like to run:
    <p><%= link_to @item.item_select, item_path(id: @item.id) %>
  <% end %>
</td>
```

Any ideas how I can run the @item call as it pertains to the 'tp.product_id' code in the html file?

Appreciate any help I can get.  Searching for this issue has left me with many purple links, but none of which address this particular issue.

**EDIT: In case anybody happens upon this that was in the same predicament as me, I have one recommendation: Learn your associations.**

Updated code:

tasks_controller.rb -->

```
def dashboard
  @tasks = Task.includes(:task_products, :storeorder).last(100)
end
```

task.rb -->

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :task_products
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :task_products
end
```

task_product.rb -->

```
class TaskProduct < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :item, foreign_key: :product_id
end
```

item.rb -->

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :task_products, foreign_key: :product_id

  def item_select
    "#{vendor_name} (#{description})"
  end
end
```

dashboard.html.erb -->

```
        <td>
          <% t.task_products.each do |tp| %>
            <% tp.items.each do |item| %>
              <p><%= link_to item.item_select, item_path(item) %></p>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, by using `Item.where` in your controller, you're actually setting `@item` to a *collection* of Items. Second, by setting it inside a loop, you're overwriting it with each TaskProduct, so only the last one will be accurate in the view.

I'm assuming you want to list [a subset of] *every* Item for *every* Task. In that case, you'd be better not to set them in your controller at all:

```
def dashboard
  @tasks = Task.includes(:task_products, :storeorder).last(100)
end
```

Instead, just loop through them in the view:

```
<% @tasks.each do |t| %>
  Task <%= t %>
  <% t.task_products.each do |tp| %>
    TaskProduct <%= tp %>
    <% tp.items.each do |item| %>
      <p><%= link_to item.item_select, item_path(item) %></p>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply @PJSCopeland.  This would work great if the items were created at the same time as the task originally was, but the Items are a pre-populated list of items that are selected when creating the task.  So unfortunately, running tp.items.each doesn't work in this case since Items don't have a task_product_id to reference.  That's why I was doing all that garbage in the controller trying to get '@items' to work.

Comment: Sounds like your model relations are misconfigured then. For a start, if the Item `id` matches the TaskProduct `product_id`, then a TaskProduct `belongs_to :item, foreign_key: :product_id`, and an Item `has_many :task_products, foreign_key: :product_id` (or `has_one :task_product, foreign_key: :product_id`). **The table with the foreign key always `belongs_to` the other.**

Comment: In fact, with that you could set up `Task.has_many :items, through: :task_products` and `Item.has_many :tasks, through: :task_products`.

Comment: We got it!  I had to mess around with the associations, but finally figured it out.  foreign_key was actually just :id.  I'll have to do some more learning with associations, because they're still a bit of a mystery to me.  I never knew about foreign_key before, and that was the winning ticket.  I'll update my post above with the correct code.  Thank you very much!  It's literally been a week I've been trying to put this damn table together!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any need of all the loops in your dashboard_controller.rb

```
@tasks.each do |task|
  task.storeorder do |storeorder|
end
task.task_products.each do |task_product|
  @item = Item.where(:id => task_product.product_id)
end
end
```

Here's what you need in html.erb:

```
# The ideal code I would like to run:
<% tp.items.each do |item| %>
  <p><%= link_to item.item_select, item_path(item) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes, the loops in the dashboard controller were just from me monkeying around trying to get it working properly.  The tp.items doesn't work though because Items aren't implicitly attached to the task_products (ie, item doesn't have a task_product_id column).  >>> SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: items.task_product_id: SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."task_product_id" = ?

Comment: You have `belongs_to :task_product` in class `Item`? You have all associations just the column is missing in the items table I guess.